# ng-click no funciona con Rows Grouping de Datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

Hola tengo una datatable que se llena con datos de una consulta, luego de llenar la tabla con los datos hago un drawCallback (datatables) con el cual creo una fila (row) a modo de agrupamiento (Imagen de Ejemplo) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el problema es que en el titulo de cada fila tengo un checkbox [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] el cual tiene asociado el ng-click de angular pero por alguna razón que desconozco el ng-ckick no funciona.
Estuve investigando y me encontre con el siguiente código:

```
.withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex){
    $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
})
```

El cual no funciono, ¿alguien tiene idea de que puede ser?
Gracias